# Storage limitations on Google Keep

Tags: online-storage, google-keep

I've tried searching for the answer but couldn't find it. Do the notes stored in Google Keep use space from the Google storage? Or is it free and unlimited like a Google doc in Google Drive?

EDIT: that's too good to believe they would give unlimited storage for pictures and audio recordings.

Any update?

Comment: FYI The [official help](https://support.google.com/keep) doesn't go into any detail in terms of what "syncs with google" means.

Comment: From everything I can gather (no official word) - google keep operates outside of google drive. You don't need a google drive account to have google keep. I can't imagine it would count against your drive quota, **yet** - but I can't find anything about any limits at all for keep. Additionally, I don't see Keep in my google dashboard or data explorer.

Comment: Any updates? With the loss of unlimited high quality photo storage I wonder if Google Keep will also be restricted soon.

Answer (score 10):

Tested this a minute ago: 19,999 characters is the upper limit for text in **each** Google Keep note, not including the title or any images. additionally, 999 characters maximum are allowed in the title. I was able to upload 7 images totaling 3.0MB to the same note after the above text limits were reached. I assume more images can be attached to the same note, but I stopped at 7.

Comment: it's much more than seven. can someone find the upper bound?

Comment: Additional note (pun intended):  I found that a checkbox list in Keep has a limit of 999 total items (including the checked items).

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is no limit for Google Keep storage according to [this article](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/web/google-keep-vs-evernote-vs-apple-notes-1139656).

Comment: Keep in mind that, although Google Keep might offer unlimited storage of pictures and audio recordings, each individual text note is limited to about 10,000 characters (which is about 2,000 words).  Even if you want to store more than that in a single note, you can't.  You'll have to split the note into two or more shorter notes.  For more information, try a Web search for [ `google keep character limit` ].

Comment: Thanks for your info. I still don't understand why Keep has limit characters in note.

Comment: @unforgettableid then how can I avert the situation when I want to save all in a single note?

Comment: wait, can i attach movie files (1 to 25 GB files) to notes on keep?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Google Product [forum answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/_mgdBX6y53A;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Akeep$20storage$20space) no data attached to Google Drive account.

Comment: Can you summarize what's at the link, please.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for the number of items in a Google Keep list. By my estimate, that limit is 1,000.

[image: Google Keep list items left]

Answer (score -1):

All the Google Keep data is stored in your android phone in main memory. The Default size appears to be 2 GB on my phone. When I used up the 2GB, it prompted me to give it more space, but by then the phone was almost full. I have not found the place where the settings are to change it yet. Seems Like a space hog. Wish I could just put it on the SD card.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this? How do you know it used up "2GB"? How much memory in total does your phone have?

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a comment on another answer or whether it's meant to stand on its own.  Could you clarify?

Comment: I don't think Google Keep storage is kept on the device, because I have 3 devices using Keep and the data is identical on each.