# How scalable is Google Keep?

Tags: google-keep

I'm considering the migration of my entire project planning (and "life planning") from e-kalender.de to Google Keep.

I have about 5000 entries there, sometimes consisting of a few pages of text, but no images, audios or similar. Apart from that, these entries are organized in about a dozen groups (similar to Keep's "Labels").

Does anyone have a similar amount of data in Google Keep, and does it work / sync flawlessly and across devices (iPhone, iPad, Web version)?

Comment: [Relevant](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79225/1512).

Comment: Anecdotal: a couple of years ago I tried keeping an extensive set of notes in Google Keep. Something went wrong when I quickly moved several notes in a row between active and archived. Never saw them again. Never  used Google Keep again.

Comment: I've just set a few reminders, and despite refreshing like a madman and logging out and back in on my iPhone, iPad and the Web version, the Web version never showed those notes under "Reminders", while both idevices did. Doesn't make a very reliable impression.

Comment: @instinctive FWIW, the Web version is "supposed" to update instantaneously. If I make changes on the iPad (including adding "Reminders") then the Web version does appear to update "before my very eyes", without having to hit "Refresh". However, I don't use the Web version a great deal TBH.

Comment: I don't think Google Keep is to be trusted as a serious product. It mostly exists for quick note-taking purposes. For (mostly personal) project planning and note taking, the ultimate tool to use is always Emacs' org-mode. Or else for less powerful tools Evernote and OneNote would still be much more reliable than Google Keep.

Comment: @Minestrone: _"a couple of years ago"_ Keep hasn't really been around for more than a couple years.

Comment: @AlE. True, it was announced in March 2013. I was an early adopter and early quitter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have that much data but I do use Google Keep Chrome app & the Android app to keep track of my todos and also store some important stuff as well. It has worked great for me so far with no sync issues.

That being said, Google does have a history of killing products without much notice.

Answer (score 3):

Google Keep's maximum characters per document is about 20300. So depending on what you mean by a few pages, some of the bigger documents may have to be broken up, and that may be a deal killer.

My experience is that with my phone synced, it takes a minute to update my daily notes to Google Keep. Then I combine them to a Google Drive doc at the end of the week. This works well for me, but if people need to share constantly updated documents, it might not. But it gets cluttered with 10 or more documents, even though tags are a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the way you want to scale.

When it comes to number of notes, I only reached ~100ish but had no problems.

When using a todo list-style note, however, when you reach more than 500 entries, both iOS and Android apps start lagging to a degree it becomes unusable. It is much better on a web interface, but you can notice a performance hit anyway.

Answer (score -1):

After more than two years of filling it with notes and photos etc it has slowed down, which may be my phone but not sure, docs has fast keyboard response, keep has slowed down dramatically but can use it.